# Correct type for TypeScript dictionary

Tags: typescript

I am trying to map over a dictionary and copy its keys and values to another dictionary but I am getting the following type error: `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

```js
interface ValueOrError <V>
{
    value: V | undefined
    error: string
}

function process_num (value: number | undefined, error: string): MaybeNumber
{
    return { value, error }
}

function process_str (value: string | undefined, error: string): MaybeString
{
    return { value, error }
}

interface MaybeNumber extends ValueOrError<number> {}
interface MaybeString extends ValueOrError<string> {}

const params = {
    volume: process_num(2, ""),
    time: process_num(undefined, "No time specified"),
    units: process_str("m", ""),
}

const ok_params: {[k in keyof typeof params]: Exclude<(typeof params[k])["value"], undefined>} = {} as any

let failure = false
;(Object.keys(params) as (keyof typeof params)[]).forEach(key =>
{
    const result = params[key]

    if (result.value === undefined)
    {
        console.error(`Error in "${key}" param`, result.error)
        failure = true
    }
    else
    {
        // Error:  "Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'."
        ok_params[key] = result.value
    }
})
```

It would appear I need to narrow the type of `result` to remove this erroneous error.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIBqSA2BXGAeTgFE44B7OdAHkwD5QBvUdN9AN1wIC4t0APujwQAJjASQYo1u3iU4fAM5Q4kAOagAvqFAIRKKGAoR0AB0polSgPoQ8AW3QAKLvhh97DgEbxBwsQkpUQAadHkqZVUNAEo+AFkkAE9fADlHXzhmWTY4GCg8OFMmTm4YMIjqHRBqvQMjE3NLGGsbFWpXMqi1CHV-EXFJCGkK8kj0dtiE5N8AZWje7JB2dDyCovQStwJRhXRq2vBoeGQ0dESUmHSfPxgAD1gxJSwy4jIFGi9M+k3qyFhEKgMBc5gs+vdHqJnth3G8xnAaJNej8mIcUCYVOYkHAkA5ngBeTY5TgUfAODxNChWWxeZwAJjCACJGTEQsSjOS+BYqS0aY5nAMgsNQuhGakKOgORglGYYCgwJJpCy2ct2CIwFAlFzmq12s5GQ5GUzldpdCB0RBMRQANY2MzY3FazYAbWt6Eg6GtMCSFAQkqSst9WJxeIAunwSHcUPhxDRnFAAzAg-aQ0pXaGYs7GdsYIzQ2FBUNpPQtOhCaj0EhnkgIEkzTh8uhkGB8Hky03cEoYKAANzOQjeABWcqgADovUklM4U46YpXns4J0GE4G-TO8ZmM6OEFQSKgABaL71lxggFiqtgWzF5JR4HBQdvrtMT0NmlYKlw3u9jnNl-GEwtghiYlzxWFYr1JGBR0qZwAAN3iod1TEZAASJgJy0Rlg1xWCwi-e9oPhYCLzA5tWwwQlVAIYlqhWGAcC7EDiRWG07QdPFXW9UN23wn8yho7RiKAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both value maybe `undefined` that mean we cannot only use typeof for narrowing types.

To narrow down the type, [`discriminated unions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions)  would be the best way to do so. Result would be as follow:

#### Example

```
interface ValueOrError <V>
{
    value: V | undefined
    error: string
}

interface MaybeNumber extends ValueOrError<number> {
  kind: `MaybeNumber` // add this line to let TypeScript narrow the type by the value
}
interface MaybeString extends ValueOrError<string> {
  kind: `MaybeString`// add this line to let TypeScript narrow the type by the value
}

function process_num (value: number | undefined, error: string): MaybeNumber
{
    return { value, error, kind:`MaybeNumber` }
}

function process_str (value: string | undefined, error: string): MaybeString
{
    return { value, error, kind: `MaybeString` }
}


const params = {
    volume: process_num(2, ""),
    time: process_num(undefined, "No time specified"),
    units: process_str("m", ""),
}

const ok_params: {[k in keyof typeof params]: Exclude<typeof params[k], undefined>} = {} as any

let failure = false
;(Object.keys(params) as (keyof typeof params)[]).forEach(key =>
{
    const result = params[key]

    if (result.value === undefined)
    {
        console.error(`Error in "${key}" param`, result.error)
        failure = true
    }
    else if(key === `units` && result.kind === `MaybeString`) { // handle type of MaybeString for both side
        ok_params[key] = result
    }
    else if ((key === `volume` || key === `time`) && result.kind === `MaybeNumber`){ // handle type of MaybeNumber for lhs and rhs
        ok_params[key] = result
    }
})
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIBqSA2BXGAeTgFE44B7OdAHkwD5QBvUdN9AN1wIC4t0APujwQAJjASQYo1u3iU4fAM5Q4kAOagAvqFCRYiVBgCySAJ4AjGADk8AWyvUYAD1hilWbkVLkqNCPaO9OgsIGwA1pCifAAGppY2gfAx6AD0qehIoqLoUAAWYB44UrkU6DgwUOgAKmYADjAAyihqdVUQSL4A7rl5GFD1GBZmvRhc+DDaetDwyGjo8VaNqhroLm6iHtgTxGQKNCpqEOrBoRFRsYtNK8cx6ZnZvYXlJVBlFVW1Dc2t7Z2UPXy-UG6GGo04XimIFACBEKCgYAoEHQdUoaCUSgA+gE7OgABTjXjoHGOQTCMQSKSiAA0a18inQhw0AEo+FdbA54MxZGw4JU8HBkUwIRNafIqLTImIeHFzFYOY4UjoQMqYXCEUiUWiYBjMYd8YSYMobuoySJxJIINIxfTjUd1KyFnLrvbuWF2HyoAKhSKCDaFJKLuhZQllvalVDdCAUEiVCjOkg7B4ALwhHmcCj4OxGrUUdFYnF4gBMtIARKXmdT0wjs3xUXmdQX7HjzZSrTT0KXrGUaxglA0UGBJNIK1X3WwRGAoEo69rdYc8aW7KWy6PI9HY1UKOFMXUE0m+EwANrhdCQdDhGBmCgIXKDG-xuCJpQAXT4JGcKHw4hoAwaD73J8kxPF9aVbS1pHoLR0FTJhoKQDwkAgMwow+dBkDAfA+Rg9DcCUSYQAAbjxQgLAAKxgeEADpLzMJQ8UA59mUyDw8Voh8-xgAD9yUZkjxfZkqIQKgSFQPI2KvGDGBAM52BjCA4z5JQ8BwKpU0Y4DaJfKN2DPW88SUlSoCow0YOTVNwKpZl01k3S2HkpRMxgKjxTgPEYj2Kgz2RUsABImForRS0fRMYlpQzVJc+lrPHOyMKwjBU1UAh02VXSYBwfC9IkkZzNTGJJ2nFIADJivQCLjKlHI8uDK4ww0GJmOFe48iQ0QKjvBp0AfOqTXQryLAofJGTAcR0107ddx4k8rxfHCKtS9MMqyod8Rysz8o4TN7BgFIBCEWiNuDXtGvQUryp1IyaKiI6Q3lJI4Ea5qMlasQOs47rb3ZB7+uoHA8kQsRyoB8b2EmjSlBmsw5tTBbYuVLQYqAA)

Comment: Thanks Edwin, yes that does work.  Shame there's not a more elegant way.  I'd really prefer to avoid having the large conditionals checking the key value.  Also with this method you do not need a descriminated union.  Just checking the key works.

Answer (score 0):

[@Edwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032429/539490) allows you to get typesafe code and can be simplified to achieve this without using descriminated unions (though descriminated unions is the easier solution for more complex types of `result.value`).  I'd still prefer a more elegant typesafe method but I do not think this is currently possible, nor am I sure this would ever be possible to narrow the type of `result` to be based on the `key`:

```js
// ...

;(Object.keys(params) as (keyof typeof params)[]).forEach(key =>
{
    const result = params[key]

    if (result.value === undefined)
    {
        console.error(`Error in "${key}" param`, result.error)
        failure = true
    }
    else if ((key === "volume" || key === "time") && typeof result.value === "number")
    {
        ok_params[key] = result.value
    }
    else if (key === "units" && typeof result.value === "string")
    {
        ok_params[key] = result.value
    }

// ...
```